# Cannot query ContractId on Quote object in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, quote

I wrote a trigger on Contract, where I need to query all the related Quotes of contract. I wrote below query:

`List<Quote> quotes = [Select ContractId From Quote Where ContractID IN: ids];`

I get this error:

> No such column 'ContractId' on entity 'Quote' ...

I tried to execute this query in Query Editor of Developer Console and as Anonymous apex. Both Worked. I also checked the permission for the field. In fact I can see the field on the Record's Page Layout.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check the API Version of your trigger. It might be an older version, where the field did not exist yet.

Comment: I actually couldn't find any contract related field on the Quote in [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Quote.htm). Maybe there is a ContactId/ContractId Typo?

Comment: So yeah if it's not a standard field, take a look at the Fields page for the Quote object. It's probably a custom lookup which means the API name is more likely to be `Contract__c` or whatever else was chosen by the admin who set it up.

Comment: @CharlesT There is a standard Contract field.

Comment: @sfdcfox any idea why it is not listed in the documentation?

Comment: @Basti No. Presumably, it's simply an oversight by the documentation team. If recommend leaving feedback for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Quote.ContractId` field requires at least API version 31.0. Please edit your class' or trigger's metadata to at least version 31.0.